# Lpr -module in Python

Tags: python, printing, lpr

**How can you call lpr in Python?**

It is not in the sys -module which is surprising.

I aim to use the lpr as follows shown by pseudo-code

```
10*i for i in range(77):              
      lpr --pages(i,i+1) file.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of, I don't understand your pseudo code. (What does `10*i for i in range(77):` mean in this case?)

Generally, you use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to run external commands. [ActiveState recipe 511505](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511505/) shows an example specifically with `lpr`. Basically, you can invoke `lpr` like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['lpr', 'some_filename'])
```

**However:** Depending on your version of `lpr`, there may not be an option to select a subset of all pages, or this functionality may be available only for [e.g. dvi files](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?lpr).

**Edit:** Since you seem to want to print selected pages of PDF files, have a look at the [PDF toolkit](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/). That software appears to provide splitting functionality. Also, make sure that directly printing PDF files is supported. You may need to convert the input to postscript first (e.g. using [`pdf2ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdf2ps)). Of course you can automate these tasks using `subprocess.Popen` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just call it from the commandline:

```
import commands

for i in range(77):
    # I'm making no assumptions about lpr command syntax here.
    cmd = "lpr --pages(%s,%s) file.pdf" % (2*i, 2*i+1)
    commands.getoutput(cmd)
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but pycups appears to be python bindings for cups.

http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/pycups/

Comment: To save time for anyone reading this: pycups lets you manage printers and queues, not print to them.

Comment: @NickJohnson More specifically, the API would appear to indicate that you can [print files present on the local filesystem](http://pythonhosted.org/pycups/cups.Connection-class.html#printFile), but you cannot stream data to a printer. This means pycups is definitely not a stand-in for lpr if you are not looking to create temporary files, which seems to be an [intentional exclusion](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/system-config-printer-devel/2013-December/000157.html).